# Nodejs importing ES6 library fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to import ES6 library in my Node app. I tried to do it both ES5 and ES6 script. What I am trying to do is simply :

```
import 'gnosisjs/src';
```

what I get is :

```
gnosistest/node_modules/gnosisjs/src/index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import * as config from './config';
                                                          ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I am running app via this command :

```
node -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill test.js
```

importing other standard libraries seems to be working.

Edit: Screenshots of the projects :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHoF5.png

and dependencies :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NObnD.png

Comment: FYI - the generally accepted acyronym for ECMAScript is ES, rather than EC. I've updated your question, should make it a little more obvious what you're asking.

Comment: Have you got a `.babelrc` file? You'll need to install `babel-preset-es2015` or similar to get module imports (and possibly other ES6 syntax depending on Node version) working

Comment: @JoeClay thank you, you are right of course.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue. Yes I do have .babelrc and babel-preset-es2015 installed. I will update question with screenshots of the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there was an issue within gnosis library. With latest release problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

The `src` directory contains the source files. You should import the compiled files from the `dist` directory:

```
import 'gnosisjs/dist/gnosis';
```

You also should run your app using `babel-node`:

```
babel-node test.js
```

Comment: It gives same effect.

Comment: still the same effect